# Extract or parse value from Json object in C#

Tags: c#, json, powerbi

C# beginner here. I have the below working snippet that gets a Json object from the Power BI api. (Code originates from this post: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Data-refresh-error-via-API/m-p/1437517).

```
static void getRefreshHistory(string groupId, string datasetId, int lastNRrefresh = 1)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(String.Format("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{0}/datasets/{1}/refreshes/?$top={2}", groupId, datasetId,lastNRrefresh));
        //POST web request to create a datasource.
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        //Add token to the request header
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

        //Write JSON byte[] into a Stream
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
             
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);
            foreach (var refresh in responseJson.value) {
                Console.WriteLine("Dataset {0} refreshed is {1}",datasetId,refresh["status"]);
                Console.WriteLine("starttime at {0} endtime at {1}", refresh["startTime"], refresh["endTime"]);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            } 
        } 
    }
```

It returns a string that is deserialized into a collection of json objects:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#refreshes",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 753920385,
      "refreshType": "ViaApi",
      "startTime": "2020-11-23T12:59:56.31Z",
      "endTime": "2020-11-23T13:00:40.937Z",
      "status": "Completed",
      "requestId": "ee12c9ab-e3a8-41b2-9056-81a0cc090251"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to (1) just extract the endTime and status values, and (2) get rid of the foreach loop near the bottom, since I am always only getting the first value, but I haven't been able to get the syntax right. I don't expect anyone to solve my problems for me, but could you please tell me what I need to read up on in order to solve it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with JObject

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json6.json");
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var item in JArray.Parse(jobj["value"].ToString()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["startTime"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item["endTime"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item["status"]);
}
```

If you what to read the first value element then you can try this

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json6.json");
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(jobj["value"][0]["startTime"]);
Console.WriteLine(jobj["value"][0]["endTime"]);
Console.WriteLine(jobj["value"][0]["status"]);
```